# Efficient algorithm for a distance on strings

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Consider two sequences $a = (a_i)_{i=1}^n$, $b = (b_i)_{i=1}^m$, $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ with elements in $M$. For two sequences $[n],[m]$, call $$\Gamma([n], [m]) = \big\{E \subseteq [n] \times [m]\mid \forall i < j, k>l: \neg ((i,k) \in E \wedge (j, l) \in E) \wedge \pi_1(E) = [n] \wedge \pi_2(E) = [m]\big\}$$ the set of *weakly increasing matchings* (that's a title I made up for them).

Define a function $\tilde d \colon M^\mathbb N \times M^\mathbb N \to \mathbb R^+$,
$$
\widetilde d(a, b) = \min_{E \in \Gamma ([n],[m])} \sum_{i, j \in E} d(a_i, b_{j}).
$$
This should define a metric, which I'm tempted to call *string matching distance* (which seems to be, after a brief google, already taken by the edit distance, which is different). Questions:

- Does this metric have a name?
- For which classes of metrics is this metric efficiently computable/approximable?

Comment: As you've written it this is not a metric, because the minimum always occurs when $E$ is empty.  Assuming the definition you probably meant to write (namely, adding the condition that the projections of $E$ onto $[n]$ and $[m]$ are surjective) it is straightforward to write down a dynamic-programming approach to compute $\tilde{d}$ that is quadratic in $\max(m,n)$.  So the only interesting question in this post is for what metrics you can approximate this in sub-quadratic time; this may be more suitable for cstheory.SE.

Comment: What does "two sequences $[n]$, $[m]$" mean?  As written, your definition seems very specific to (I assume you mean, or maybe you prefer to shift by $1$) $[n] = \{0, \dotsc, n - 1\}$ and $m = \{0, \dotsc, m - 1\}$; do you really mean it to apply to arbitrary sequences?

Comment: Thanks, dvitek, dynamic programming was a good call. The only think I don't see is how to make it quadratic (and not cubic): I thought that one needs to go trough the matched index of k = n downto 1 and the one for k+1 (which would be stored). That would give cubic time.